# Jquery that changes hidden input value when another field is altered and how to reverse it?

Tags: jquery, forms, input, hidden

I am using Jquery to change the value of a hidden input to 'True' when the user inputs a value into a different form field.  It looks like this

```
$(function(){
$('#vmake').change(function(){
$('#carsearch').val('True');
});
```

It works great except if the user changes their mind and deletes their input, the hidden input keeps the value of 'True'.  I want to make it so that if they change their mind and delete the #vmake input, it changes the value of #carsearch back to 'False'.

I would really appreciate any input on how this is accomplished.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function(){
$('#vmake').change(function(){
  $('#carsearch').val($(this).val() != '' ? 'true' : '');
});
```

This sets the value to 'true' if #vmake has a value, or '' if it doesn't.

Comment: You are the best, Thanks Paul.  I will check the correct box as soon as it lets me!

Comment: Actually I have 1 more question, what if its a checkbox, this works for my text inputs, what do I do if I use a .click instead of .change when someone checks a checkbox, then unchecks it in the same situation

Comment: nevermind I got this answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712340/jquery-changing-hidden-input-value-when-a-checkbox-is-checked-and-reverse-when-u